# Desplazarse al id de un div de otra ventana con href="url+'#id'"

Tags: jquery, html5, thymeleaf

Tengo una duda porque no sé el por qué no me funciona bien.

Tengo unos enlaces los cualses se generan con un bucle y redireccionan a otra ventana y que está llamando a un ID para que se posicione en la sección que contiene dicho ID

```
<a class="link" th:href="@{${thymeleafMap.get('CATALOG_MAPPING_DETAIL_VIEW_NO_VIEW_NO_PARAM')}+${item.oaiIdentifierB64}+'#copias'(tabId=${solrSearchWeb.solrSearch.tabId})}" th:if="${item.totalCopiesByPage != null and item.totalCopiesByPage > 0}" th:aria-label="#{result.copies} + ' ('  +  ${item.totalCopiesByPage} + ')'">
     <th:block th:text="#{result.copies} + ' :'  + ${item.totalCopiesByPage}"/>
</a>
```

En cada enlace se genera una url tipo

```
https://localhost:8082/carpeta1/carpeta2/url?tabId=1654670323100#copias
```

Este enlace me abre una ventana que tiene varias capas y una de ellas tiene el
**id="copias"** y este link debería posicionar la ventana que abre en el div del id.

```
<div id="copias">contenido del div</div>
```

Una parte de la url se muestran según lo que hayan encontrado en BBDD y hay veces que cuando clickeo al enlace, me lo hace bien, me abre la ventana y se desplaza la ventana posicionandose correctamente en el div del ID y otras no, sólo me redirecciona a la ventana pero no se posiciona en dicho ID.

he creado una función en JQuery con un alert para ver si entra en dicha función y hay enlaces que entran a dicha función y otros no y no sé por qué si en el buche genera todos los enlaces con los mismos parámetros

```
scroll_anchor : async $capa=>{
     alert('entra scroll');
},
```

Alguien me podría ayudar con el por qué algunas veces me posiciona bien y otras no?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué navegador estás utilizando? En mi caso particular (Firefox 100 ahora mismo) suele pasarme con algunos enlaces de aquí del sitio, refresco la página y ahí sí se muestra en la posición que debería.

Comment: he probado con chrome y firefox y en ninguno de los 2 me funciona correctamente un enlace se posiciona bien pero a lo mejor el siguiente solo abre la ventana pero no se posiciona ni refrescando la ventana

Comment: acabo de limpiar al 100% la caché en firefox y la de chrome y ahora me funciona en firefox pero no en chrome